# Looking up a column name in a different data.table and use the information when there is a match

Tags: r, for-loop, hmisc

I would like to store the `Group` information of the data.table below (`DT1`) as a label for the column names of a second data.table. The column names of the second data.table (`DT2`) are identical to the `nr` information of the first data.table.

```
set.seed(1)
    DT1 <- data.table(nr= paste0('x',1:100),Group = c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10),rep("C",10),rep("D",10),rep("E",10),rep("F",10),rep("G",10),rep("H",10),rep("I",10),rep("J",10)),
                          id = c(rep(1,20),rep(2,20),rep(3,20),rep(4,20),rep(5,20)),
                          Time = rep(seq(as.Date("2010-01-03"), length=20, by="1 month") - 1,5),
                          norm = round(runif(100)/10,2),
                          y = sample(100,100),
                          x2 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
                          x3 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
                          x4 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
                          x5 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2))
    DT2 <- data.table(matrix(0, ncol=100, nrow=2, dimnames=list(NULL, 
                 paste0('x',1:100))))
```

I have previously done something like this:

```
library(Hmisc)
for (i in seq_len(ncol(DT2))) {Hmisc::label(IV[[DT1$`nr`[i]]]) <- ES1obs$Group[i]}
```

But this has a lot of problems when the amount of columns are not identical.

How can I write the code so that it will compare the `nr` column of `DT1` with the column names of `DT2`, and add the `Group` column when they are a match?

Desired outcome:

```
label(DT2$x1) <- "A"
label(DT2$x2) <- "A"
...
label(DT2$x100) <- "J"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `match` assuming all the column names of `DT2` are always present in `DT1$nr`

```
library(Hmisc)

for (i in seq_len(ncol(DT2))) { 
    label(DT2[[i]]) <-  DT1$Group[match(names(DT2)[i], DT1$nr)] 
 }

head(label(DT2))
# x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6 
#"A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" 

tail(label(DT2))
# x95  x96  x97  x98  x99 x100 
# "J"  "J"  "J"  "J"  "J"  "J"
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!